# Unable to update Ionic 5.0.0 to a newer version

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I got the message bellow:

```
Update available 5.0.0 → 5.4.1│
Run npm i -g ionic to update.
```

Then I run "npm i -g ionic", and that is what is show:

```
npm WARN deprecated superagent@4.1.0: Please note that v5.0.1+ of superagent removes User-Agent header by default, therefore you may need to add it yourself (e.g. GitHub blocks requests without a User-Agent header).  This notice will go away with v5.0.2+ once it is released.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/ionic -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
+ ionic@5.4.2
updated 1 package in 7.726s
```

But the version stays on 5.0.0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you're on mac try using : sudo npm install -g ionic